# How to remove newline from char *?

Tags: c++, string, newline

I've got a variable: `char * tmp` and I do few operations with it. Finally, I've got something like this `"fffff"` but sometimes before fffff is `"\n"`. How can I delete it?

Comment: I think the best course of action would be to prevent it from getting there in the first place.  Can you show us some code that describes how you are ending up with strings containing `\n`?

Comment: If that is `C++` consider using `std::string` instead of `char *`

Comment: Search and replace. `strchr`, `strpbrk` for `char *` and `find_first_of` for `std::string`. Take your pick.

Comment: @whiteangle you can always convert from a cstring to a std::string by using its constructor and from a std::string to a cstring by using std::string::c_str().

Comment: I had this problem reading internationalised html files into my program with libXML, had a very fast C/C++ implementation, it's non trivial but low level primitives produced a marked increase in performance. I'll have a rummage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char *tmp = ...;

// the erase-remove idiom for a cstring
*std::remove(tmp, tmp+strlen(tmp), '\n') = '\0'; // removes _all_ new lines.
```

Comment: What do you need to `#include` for this?

Comment: @Splatmistro `#include <algorithm>`. [See here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: what is meaning of assigning '\0' here?

Answer (score 4):

In your question, you are talking about passing this string to a socket. When passing a char* pointer to something like a socket which will copy it, the code to do so is very straightforward.

In this case, you can do this:

```
if (tmp[0] == '\n')
  pass_string(tmp+1); // Passes pointer to after the newline
else
  pass_string(tmp);   // Passes pointer where it is
```

Answer (score 2):

In C:

```
#include <string.h>
tmp[strcspn(tmp, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Comment: It was a C++ question, not C

Answer (score 1):

If tmp is allocated dynamically remember to free it using `tmp`:

```
if (tmp[0] == '\n') {
    tmp1 = &tmp[1];
}
else {
    tmp1 = tmp;
}

// Use tmp1 from now on
```